# How do we show that a matrix satisfying the following conditions is scalar multiple of the identity matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose $D$ is diagonal with diagonal entries $d_1, d_2, \cdots, d_n$. Furthermore, suppose that $Dx$ is orthogonal to $Dy$ whenever $x,y \in \mathbb{C}^n$ are orthogonal. Show that $D$ is a scalar multiple of the identity matrix, that is show that $d_1 = d_2 = \cdots = d_n$.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You might start by writing out what those two orthogonality conditions mean algebraically.

Comment: This is not true in general. Take the matrix D with diagonal entries $1$, $i$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$. Then this is a unitary matrix and so preserves inner product...What can we say is that modulus of $ d_i$'s are same....